# Как правильно создавать функции?

Tags: c++, c

Работая со старым кодом, столкнулся с интересным стилем.

После подключения библиотек и определение глобальных переменных идет `main`, а в ней функции, которые уже должны работать. Фишка в том, что сами функции создаются после `main` в конце кода. Неужели процессор не теряет такты, когда  ему приходится читать сначала команды, потом искать их определение а потом снова  читать и только потом выполнять?

Я понимаю, что команды и переменные находятся в разных сегментах памяти отведенной для программы, но хотел узнать, как правильно писать функции. Где их создавать и где определять?

Comment: *"функции создаются после мейна в конце кода"* - С/С++ является компилируемым языком и все функции создаются во время компиляции.

Comment: Процессор ничего не ищет - он по сути получает машинную команду `CALL` с адресом, по которому нужно сделать вызов. Разобрать исходный текст и скомпилировать его в машинные коды - дело компилятора, подставить нужные адреса - линковщика/компоновщика. Все немного сложнее, но в первом приближении можно считать так...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не важно, где *определяется* функция, важно лишь, чтобы к моменту ее использования она была *объявлена*.

---

Попытаюсь объяснить простыми словами.

Во-первых, вам нужно понять [разницу](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410563/what-is-the-difference-between-a-definition-and-a-declaration) между *объявлением* и *определением*:

- *Объявление* (англ. *declaration*) функции несет информацию об имени функции, типе возвращаемого ею значения и списке ее параметров. То есть всю информацию об *интерфейсе*, с помощью которого эта функция может быть использована.
- *Определение* (англ. *definition*) же, в свою очередь, несет информацию о том, что внутри этой функции происходит. То есть то, как функция устроена внутри, какова ее *реализация*.

Чтобы вызвать какую-либо функцию компилятору всегда нужно знать тип всех ее аргументов (чтобы правильно эти аргументы передать). Компилятор не сможет вызвать функцию, если не знает о списке ее аргументов, просто потому что не будет знать, как эту функцию правильно вызвать.

И здесь уже стоит сказать о том, что компилятор может скомпилировать код, использующий некторую функцию, даже не зная *определения* самой этой функции. Это приводит к широчайшим возможностям (раздельная компиляция, динамически подключаемые библиотек и так далее).

Например, вы наверняка сталкивались с использованием функции `printf` из стандартной библиотеки:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf("Hello, World!\n");
}
```

Это программа компилируется и отлично работает. Но ведь у нас нет ни объявления, ни определения функции `printf`! Как компилятор вообще смог все это скомпилировать?

На самом деле, объявление функции у нас есть, и содержится оно в заголовочном файле `<stdio.h>`<sup>1</sup> и [выглядит](https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/libio/stdio.h.html) (один из возможных вариантов) так:

```
extern int printf (const char *__restrict __format, ...);
```

Это объявление, которое называют *прототипом* (англ. *function prototype*), говорит компилятору, как нужно вызывать эту функцию. И компилятор успешно генерирует ассемблерный код для ее вызова.

Объявление же этой функции становится известно только во время запуска программы, во время [динамической линковки](https://qna.habr.com/q/489534) библиотеки, содержащей это определение. В роли библиотеки в данном случае выступает стандартная библиотека языка C, вернее ее конкрентая реализация ([GNU C Library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_C_Library), в моем случае).

---

<sup>1. В теории, мы можем вообще не подключать `<stdio.h>`, а скопировать протип функции `printf` прямо в наш код. Хотя делать так, конечно, не стоит.</sup>